# Подскажите пожалуйста как в laravel правильно залогинится чтоб он видел в база данных, если логин равно login, а пароль равно passwors. Спасибо

Tags: php, laravel

```
$data = new userModel();
$data->email = $r->email;
$data->password = Hash::make($r->password);
```

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь стандартной аутентификацией Laravel.
Сделайте все как указано в инструкции и все будет работать!
https://laravel.su/docs/6.x/authentication
Не придумывайте велосипед!)